# Display each color separate with values

Tags: php

I am having trouble in printing values from database.

ITEM TABLE

```
ITEM | COLOR | MATERIAL | DIMENSIONS | CATEGORY | QUANTITY
- 01    33      05           111         12         1000.00
- 02    33      07           125         18         200.00
- 03    33      11           156         18         254.00
- 04    56      15           25          66         113.00
- 05    66      05           11          33         521.00
```

I am trying to print values in table(for each color print material dimension category)
So the output will be:

```
COLOR - > 33
MATERIAL | DIMENSION | CATEGORY  | QUANTITY
05          111          12          1000.00
07          125          18          200.00
11          156          18          254.00

COLOR - > 56
MATERIAL | DIMENSION | CATEGORY  | QUANTITY
15          25           66          113.00

COLOR - > 66
MATERIAL | DIMENSION | CATEGORY  | QUANTITY
05          11           33          521.00
```

I am using query

```
$query = "SELECT a.itemnb, b.colorname, c.materialname, d.categoryname, sum(a.quantity) as quantity 
FROM dbo_items a
JOIN dbo_color b
ON a.color=b.colorid
JOIN dbo_material c
on a.material=c.material
JOIN dbo_category
on a.category=d.categoryid
GROUP BY b.colorname, c.materialname, d.categoryname, ";
```

I am using PDO.

```
$q=$conn->query($query);
```

Now I can fetch all values in table, but that is not actually I want to make.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr class="bg-primary">
      <td data-field="color">COLOR</td>
      <td data-field="material">MATERIAL</td>
      <td data-field="dim">DIMENSIONS</td>
      <td data-field="quantity">QUANTITY</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>  
  <?php while ($r = $m->fetch()){?> 
    <tr>
      <td><?=$r['colorname']?></td>
      <td><?=$r['materialname']?></td>
      <td><?=$r['categoryname']?></td>
      <td><?=$r['quantity ']?></td>
   <?php } ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to print first color and then all material related to that color.
I am having trouble there, any help or advice is appreciated?

Comment: What exacly isn't working? The query? The php? The html/css?

Comment: What is the out put of your code show that then I can help you.

Comment: I want output like this                                                                      COLOR - > 33
MATERIAL | DIMENSION | CATEGORY  | QUANTITY
05          111          12          1000.00
07          125          18          200.00
11          156          18          254.00

COLOR - > 56
MATERIAL | DIMENSION | CATEGORY  | QUANTITY
15          25           66          113.00

COLOR - > 66
MATERIAL | DIMENSION | CATEGORY  | QUANTITY
05          11           33          521.00

Answer (score 1):

You have to **ORDER BY** 'COLOR' and not to **GROUP BY** 'COLOR'
After that yout test if you are switching to a new color

```
<?php
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr class="bg-primary">
      <td data-field="color">COLOR</td>
      <td data-field="material">MATERIAL</td>
      <td data-field="dim">DIMENSIONS</td>
      <td data-field="quantity">QUANTITY</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>  
  <?php 
    $prevColor = '';
    while ($r = $m->fetch()){?> 
    <tr>
      <td><? print ($prevColor == $r['colorname'] ? '' :  $r['colorname']) ?></td>
      <td><? print $r['materialname']?></td>
      <td><? print $r['categoryname']?></td>
      <td><? print $r['quantity ']?></td>
   <?php 
        $prevColor = $r['colorname'];} 
    ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**UPDATE**
If you can not change your query, so you have to order by COLOR your resultset

Comment: I can not use order I have to group items becase I have more items with same material dimensions, color thats why I am calculating sum.

Comment: Thats not I am looking for, I want to print color first and then all related materials dimension and quantity to that color. Thanks for helping

Comment: do you want to style tour <td> tags with color stored in database ?

Comment: not really, in my problem below line "I am trying to print values in table(for each color print material dimension category) So the output will be:" is what I am trying to get.

Answer (score 1):

First remove the `colorname` field from `group by` clause in query and add this column with `order by` means add `order by colorname` in query.

And then change from HTML and php code with the following:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr class="bg-primary">
      <td data-field="color">COLOR</td>
      <td data-field="material">MATERIAL</td>
      <td data-field="dim">DIMENSIONS</td>
      <td data-field="quantity">QUANTITY</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>  
  <?php 
  $tempColor = '';
  while ($r = $m->fetch()){
  if($tempColor != $r['colorname']) {
   ?>
   <tr><td colspan="4">Color Name: <?=$r['colorname']?></td></tr>
  <?php $tempColor = $r['colorname'];
  } else { 
  ?> 
    <tr>
      <td><?=$r['colorname']?></td>
      <td><?=$r['materialname']?></td>
      <td><?=$r['categoryname']?></td>
      <td><?=$r['quantity ']?></td>
   <?php }
   }
    ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the current colorname is equal to the previous one:

```
<?php
$currcolor=array();
$i=0;
while ($r = $m->fetch()){
    $currcolor[$i]=$r['colorname']; ?> 
    <tr>
      <td>
      <?php if($currcolor[$i] != $currcolor[$i-1]){
          echo $currcolor[$i];
      } ?>
      </td>
      <td><?php echo $r['materialname']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $r['categoryname']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $r['quantity ']; ?></td>
   <?php
    $i++;
} ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest approach is to make one query for getting all colors, then you can make loop for result from first query and use another query for getting all information related to specific color.

Example:

```
$q = 'SELECT * FROM dbo_color';
$q=$conn->query($query);

while ($res = $q->fetch()){
   $secondQ = 'SELECT * FROM relatedMaterials WHERE color = ' . $res->color;
}
```

And include in this query all html you need for creating table.
I hope this will help you.